# How to change the properties of a button in DataGridTemplateColumn in Datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to change the visibility property and the content property of a button in the DataGridTemplateColumn of a DataGrid in wpf.

XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Button  Name="btnViewTrans" Height="23" Width="75" Visibility="Hidden" />
              </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

VB

```
Private Sub grid1_LoadingRow(sender As System.Object, e As  System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs) Handles grdPermits.LoadingRow
              If not strValue="" Then
                 Dim btnViewTransaction As New Button
                 btnViewTransaction = DirectCast(e.Row.FindName("btnViewTrans"), Button)
                 btnViewTransaction.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
             End If
    End Sub
```

I'm not using MVVM. And when I use the above method it return a Null Reference error.

Comment: You are trying to find a resource in Datatemplate. Try the msdn link which will help you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4

Comment: I tried the above method but I am still get the same null reference error.. I guess i am missing something, but i am not sure what it is ..